# Find valid parameter combinations of a function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a function `f[a_,b_, c_, d_]` which is quite complex (multiple gamma functions and other nasty things). Some parameter combinations of this function produce an "Indeterminate" error. Is there a way to let Mathematica figure out (analytically or numerically) the 'valid' parameter combinations for this function?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your quick reply! The function is really complex, and it would take me days, if not weeks, to figure out all the cross dependencies of the parameters. I am only interested in the viable parameter regions for the function so my plan was to use Mathematica to figure them out analytically or numerically. Is there a class of functions, that I can use for this? What would be the alternative if I wanted to do it numerically? Big For-Loops?

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem: I can't define these regions, and was hoping Mathematica can help me figuring them out. I was hoping someone would know something about built-in multidimensional root-finding functions or something similar, that saves me from exercising the function on a large number of parameter sets...

Comment: There's no quick and easy way.  It might be possible to do something, but it'd be much easier to figure out something if you post a sample function to work with.  Also consider posting on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ , or flagging this question for migration. Most people interested in Mathematica don't read StackOverflow regularly any more.

Comment: Exactly what Szabolcs said: we need at least a sample function to work with, and you will surely get more eyes on your question at the dedicated StackExchange site for *Mathematica*.